# List of Abstract Recursive Generics

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract class

```
abstract class AbstractEntity<T extends AbstractEntity<T>> {
  Id<T> id;
  //...
}
```

The Generic declaration is mainly neccesary because of the typed Id, so a User has an id if the type Id. It works perfectly when type generic classe (like lists with these Classes) when I work only with concrete classes.

```
class UserDao {
  List<User> getAllUsers() {
    //...
  }
}
```

When I have an abstract superclass with several concrete classes e.g. a History for a business object

```
abstract HistoryElement<T extends HistoryElement<T>> {
 //...
} 

class CreateHistoryElement extends HistoryElement<CreateHistoryElement> {}
class EditHistoryElement extends HistoryElement<CreateHistoryElement> {}
```

I cannot simply write the following options:

```
class HistoryElementDao {
   List<HistoryElement<?>> getAllHistoryElements(Id<BusinessObject> boId) {/*...*/} // produces a compile error since the Parameter T is bound to extend AbstractEntity
   List<HistoryElement> getAllHistoryElements(Id<BusinessObject> boId) {/*...*/} // produces a compiler warning (not parametrized)
   List<HistoryElement<HistoryElement>> getAllHistoryElements(Id<BusinessObject> boId) {/*...*/} // produces a compiler warning (not parametrized)
   List<HistoryElement<? extends HistoryElement> getAllHistoryElements(Id<BusinessObject> boId) {/*...*/} // produces a compiler warning (not parametrized)
List<HistoryElement<HistoryElement<HistoryElement<HistoryElement<HistoryElement<HistoryElement<...>>>>>> getAllHistoryElements(Id<BusinessObject> boId) //endless recursion
```

Question: Is there a way to parametrize the class List, so that it can contain all types of HistoryElements without generating a compiler warning or error.

Comment: Your first code segment has a typo: `abstract class AbstractEntity<T extends AbstractEntity<T> {` should be `abstract class AbstractEntity<T extends AbstractEntity<T>> {`

Comment: have you tried `class HistoryElementDao { <T extends HistoryElement<T>> List<T> getAllHistoryElements(Id<BusinessObject> boId) {/*...*}}` ?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: that might work at the declaration of the method when you want to assign the return value, you need to parametrize the type List: `List<????> elements = historyElementDao.getAllHistoryElements(...);`

Comment: Can't you treat it as `List<? extends HistoryElement<?>>`?

Comment: Have you tried `abstract HistoryElement<T extends HistoryElement<T>>{ }` ?

Comment: That is also a good question actually. It is similar to the recursiveness of the Enum, or the Vector in LibGDX. Try that.

Comment: @RKajaMohideen sorry my mistak, im my sourcecode it follows this pattern, I correct that in the question. It help to bind the parameters a bit tighter, but unfortunately it does not solve the problem

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I cant treat it as `List<? extends HistoryElement<?>>` since HistoryElement cannot be parametrized with <?> as the parameter T must extend HistoryElement<T>

Comment: ugh. I'm starting to think the only way for you to make this work is by using `<T extends HistoryElement<T>> blahblah() { List<T> elements = historyElementDao.getAllHistoryElements(...); ...` everywhere you need to use `getAllHistoryElements()`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I already thougt of that solution. thats not a nice looking solution, but it works without compiler warnings and errors.

Answer (score 0):

I played a while with this, your second last attempt was pretty close, just an additional `<T>` was missing.

```
public List<AbstractEntity<? extends AbstractEntity<T>>> getAllAbstractEntitys(String boId) {}
```

seems to do the trick!
Compiler shows no warning!

Comment: I think you meant `List<AbstractHistoryEntry<? extends AbstractHistoryEntry<?>>>` but this produces a Compiler error...